# how to add custom additional password suggetions descriptions points in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I want to add few more suggestions points to existing password suggestions description in drupal 7 while registering new user. So tell me is it possible to modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched a lot for code and did lots of programming practices but nothing workout for me. Fortunately i got a module after searching whole day which fulfills my requirements.
The module [Password Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy)

will define lots of constraints for setting password. Moreover, it also provide Delay constraint for specify minimum number of hours between password change and provide lot more.
It works for me. Hopefully it also works for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your front-end theme's template.php file:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
    case 'user_profile_form':
      $form['account']['mail']['#description'] .= "And some additional stuff.";
          break;
  }
}
```

Add similar to admin theme if need be.

Clear the cache when you are done.

Alternatively try [Better field descriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_field_descriptions).

> Better field descriptions makes it possible to add themeable
>   descriptions to fields in forms.

I have never tried it but it looks like it could do the job, through just adding your own form_alter hook is much simpler.

Comment: i m using Bartik 7.41 default theme so can where to add this code plz specify i m new to drupal .

Comment: Ideally you must override even the default with your own theme (PLEASE look at [How to Customize Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/node/1114190)), but if you do not then you will add it to themes/bartik/template.php and you will change the function name to bartik_form_alter. And remember to clear the cache when you are done. Admin theme is default Seven. Same sub-folder.

Comment: I have pasted: 
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
    case 'user_profile_form':
      $form['account']['mail']['#description'] .= "This is test suggestion descriptions";
          break;
  }
}

cleared cache but it does't work !

Comment: It will work for non-admin users because they are viewing user forms on Bartik theme. For an admin you have to do it with Seven theme.

Comment: I pasted same code for theme seven also but it doest working.

Comment: Just put form_alter in your custom module and try the above solution. Instead of THEME_form_alter use MODULENAME_form_alter in your custom module.

Comment: Note that I appended the message to the existing message. If you want to replace it do this: $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = "This is test suggestion descriptions"; More than that I cannot assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit any form by creating your own module and invoking hook_form_alter().

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        $form['account']['mail']['#description'] .= "your custom text";
    }
}
```

You may have to disable and enable the module and clear the cache.

Note that if your site is multilingual, you will also have to update your translations accordingly.